# Find a function that maps x,y to $[0, n ( n + 1) / 2)$

Tags: functions, hash-function, integers

Can you find me a bijective function that maps positive integers $x, y$ such that $0 \leq x < y \leq n$ to integers in $[0, n(n+1)/2)$ to use as a hash function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there are many. One is
$$\frac{1}{2} (n-x+1) (n-x)-n-1+y.$$

Comment: Thanks! From that I also got $\frac{(x+2)(x+1)}{2} - y$

Comment: @Flowers I don't think that works. For example, let $n=3$; then both $x=0$, $y=1$ and $x=1$, $y=3$ produce $0$ using your formula. Also your formula will produce negative numbers.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I made an incorrect substitution. $\frac{(y+1)(y)}{2} - x - 1$ should be better